# Regular expression for finding a string inside a table string

Tags: regex

I have this string and I want to find what's between last `</tr>` and `</tbody>` basically `{{/tbody}}`

```
<table><tbody>{{tbody}}<tr><td></td></tr>{{tr}}<tr><td></td></tr>{{/tbody}}</tbody></table>
```

If I use **`/<\/tr>(.*?)<\/tbody>/ig`** that is going to give me both **`{{/tbody}`}** and

> **`{{tr}}<tr><td></td></tr>{{/tbody}}`**

(the value between first `</tr>` and `</tbody>`).

Would you please let me know how can I get only `{{/tbody}}`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better solution:

```
var str="<table><tbody>{{tbody}}<tr><td></td></tr>{{tr}}<tr><td></td></tr>{{/tbody}}</tbody></table>";
var startIndex=str.lastIndexOf("</tr>")+5;
var endIndex=str.indexOf("</tbody>",startIndex);
alert(str.slice(startIndex,endIndex));
```

This is not regex, but performance wise, this is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best but

```
<\/tr>(?!.*<\/tr>)(.*?)<\/tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is between the last /tr and /tbody you can expect any character but an opening and closing tag:

```
/\<\/tr\>([\w\d\{\}\/]*?)\<\/tbody\>/ig
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what engine you're using, but it basically is done like this.

```
 # (?s)</tr>((?:(?!</tr>).)*)</tbody>

 (?s)                         # Dot-All
 </tr>
 (                            # (1 start)
      (?:
           (?! </tr> )        # Lookahead, not '</tr>'
           . 
      )*
 )                            # (1 end)
 </tbody>
```